# How to retrieve user auth information in cloud firestore using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get the user information by resolving the auth. And I have an array of phone numbers and I am passing them to the auth function to get the user and I am able to do it but when the result appears the code doesn't exit. And the user who doesn't have auth but I have phone number, I want to return a dummy object. But I am unable to exist. Here are my attempts at auth code and the phoneNumber array is the array of phone numbers.

```
const getAuth = async phoneNumber => {
  try {
    return await auth.getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error === 'auth/user-not-found') {
      console.log('this number is not auth');
    }
  }
};
const getAuth = async phoneNumber => {
  try {
    return authGrowthfile.getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error) {
      return {
        phoneNumber,
        uid: null,
        email: '',
        displayName: '',
        emailVerified: false,
        disabled: false,
      };
    }
  }
};
```

I am calling this function like this:

```
const phoneNumberArray = ['+918888','+91798299']
const userRecord = await Promise.all(phoneNumberArray.map(getAuth))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing fine, you have done all things right, just a simple typo.

```
const userRecord = await Promise.all(phoneNumberArray.map(phoneNumber => getAuth(phoneNumber)))
```

Comment: i have typed this on StackOverflow  that's why the type error

Comment: Why you have two `getAuth` methods?

Comment: i have given my two tried method but the process doesn't exit

Comment: still facing the same problem i think there is some instance still running behind the scene that's why it doesn't exit